# How do I add different content for a checkbox in Django?

Tags: django, forms

How do I add different XHTML in a template for a checkbox field? I would like the following to work. I've tried to use "is_checkbox" in the example below but it doesn't work because this isn't an admin form.

```
{% for field in payment_form %}
  <p class="{% if field.is_checkbox %}checkboxes {% endif %} ">
    {% if field.is_checkbox %}
      {{ field }} {{ field.label_tag }}
    {% else %}
      {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    {% endif %}
    <span class="error">{{ field.errors }}</span>
  </p>
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it is indeed a custom form and not an admin form, you can always override the form fields/widgets for such attrs.
Like,

```
class MyCheckboxInput(forms.CheckboxInput):
    def is_checkbox(self):
        return True
```

And use *MyCheckboxInput* in form class, instead of *forms.CheckboxInput*. It will give you, the *is_checkbox* attr on template, and then your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using a TemplateTag, a custom filter to format a form.
of form {{ form|beautify_form }}
Since all the form to be displayed can be edited , this way you get away with all the formatting delegated to a separate function.